# How to get Python dictionary with the highest key value?

Tags: python, dictionary, google-maps, coordinates

I have a dictionary with latitude and longitude values passed from a different file.

```
absoluteList = {"latitude": absolute[1], "longitude": absolute[0]}
```

If we print `absoluteList` we get:

```
{'latitude': 507476711, 'longitude': -18299961}
{'latitude': 507447383, 'longitude': -18388366}
{'latitude': 507436793, 'longitude': -18459606}
{'latitude': 507427288, 'longitude': -18500804}
{'latitude': 507410993, 'longitude': -18521404}
{'latitude': 507395241, 'longitude': -18552732}
{'latitude': 507362921, 'longitude': -18550157}
{'latitude': 507344995, 'longitude': -18521404}
```

I need to print out the dictionary with the highest latitude value.

Comment: `max(absoluteList, key=itemgetter('latitude'))`. Imports: [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: @OlvinRoght itemgetter only works with integers.

Comment: Are you sure? Checked?

Comment: @OlvinRoght getting this for both methods. TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Then your input does not match with one which shown in question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```py
absoluteList = [
  {'latitude': 507476711, 'longitude': -18299961},
  {'latitude': 507447383, 'longitude': -18388366},
  {'latitude': 507436793, 'longitude': -18459606},
  {'latitude': 507427288, 'longitude': -18500804},
  {'latitude': 507410993, 'longitude': -18521404},
  {'latitude': 507395241, 'longitude': -18552732},
  {'latitude': 507362921, 'longitude': -18550157},
  {'latitude': 507344995, 'longitude': -18521404}
]

biggest_latitude = max(absoluteList, key=lambda x: x['latitude'])
```

```
{'latitude': 507476711, 'longitude': -18299961}
```

Comment: `lambda` is slower than `itemgetter()`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, for performance use `itemgetter` like you said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```py
print( max(absoluteList, key=lambda x: x['latitude']))
```

Comment: Better to use `itemgetter()`.

Answer (score 0):

The are 2 ways to do it is by

1. using `itemgetter()`

   ```
    from operator import itemgetter 
   highest_value_in_list = max(absoluteList, key=itemgetter('latitude'))`
   ```
2. using `max`:

   `highest_value_in_list = max(absoluteList, key=lambda x: x['latitude'])`

output:

```
{'latitude': 507476711, 'longitude': -18299961}
```